# service get automatically deregister from consul after a period of time

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, consul, spring-cloud-consul, consul-health-check

we have implemented Microservice Architecture.

When we deploy a service it perfectly register itself over consul.

But after some time it gets automatically deregister.

No logs in service as well.

Comment: How are you registering these services to Consul? Are the Consul agents which you're registering the services against being restarted?

Comment: No the consul agents are not restarted.

Comment: Also we have a spring boot application which got registered to consul on boot up using consul client dependency.